# Control bar not showing in IE8 or IE9

Tags: css, video.js

I'm using 4.1.0 in both video.js and video-js.css.  I can see the control bar in chrome but not IE8 or IE9.  I see a progress bar and the time but no play/pause, volume control, or full screen icon.

My video tag looks like:

```
<video id="myMovie" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" autobuffer width="800" height="480" ></video>
```

Comment: I suggest you to post your Html code somewhere to allow other users to check the behaviour.

Comment: This sounds like a embedded font problem.  How are you pulling in the script, locally or from the CDN?  If you are pulling it in locally, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148393/video-js-custom-font-not-working-in-firefox/18154768#18154768

Answer (score 0):

I think 4.1.0 had a few browser issues. Check out my version here which works on all browsers, is responsive, and works with multiple players = http://www.andy-howard.com/recreate-bbc-iplayer/index.html

Comment: Actually, I thought I had the latest... I'll make sure I do and I'll check out your site.  Thanks!