# Icons not showing on firefox

Tags: firefox, utf-8, fonts, icons, video.js

Using VideoJS and the player's icons aren't loading in my Firefox (22.0). Works in Chrome and IE8, supposedly.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [video-js custom font not working in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148393/video-js-custom-font-not-working-in-firefox)

Answer (score 2):

I was having this problem on Firefox (but not Chrome) and at first I saw several references to making sure your server recognizes the SVG mime type as mentioned in these articles

https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/509

http://kaioa.com/node/45

I tried these and it didn't work, but then I uploaded a simple html file with a videojs example on it and it only worked on the server which I had the videojs package on (I was referring to an outside URL in these javascript lines

```
<link href="//domain.com/video-js/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//domain.com/video-js/video.js"></script>
<script>
videojs.options.flash.swf = "http://domain.com/video-js/video-js.swf"
</script>
```

So, I realized my mistake and I just installed videojs in the same domain as my website and the problem disappeared. I found a few notes stating that Firefox is a bit more strict in this regard.